# Integer points on a line.

Tags: coordinate-systems

Is there a formula for finding the integral points on a line segment? I've tried moving through the graph to find out the answer.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The slope is 44/33=4/3, so for each three integer steps in the x direction you move 4 integer steps in the y direction. All you have to do now is count these steps.